# Why does my main activity get recreated and not resumed when I finish using the top activity?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-lifecycle

I've built a simple Android app (new to Android dev and Kotlin) and I'm trying to retain some state of my main activity after starting a second activity. The way I'm starting the second activity is by clicking on a action bar item and then:

```
val intent = Intent(this, InfoActivity::class.java)
startActivity(intent)
```

Starting the new Activity works fine, but when I exit the second activity by doing:

```
override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {

    finish()

    return super.onSupportNavigateUp()
}
```

the main activity will get recreated (i.e. onCreate gets called) but I just want it to resume (i.e. onResume). What do I need to change for it to resume and not get recreated?

And for some strange reason, it seems to get created twice (i.e. it runs through onCreate twice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for your first activity in `AndroidManifest.xml` add this

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```